# Swift return random element from array into text

Tags: arrays, swift, random, swiftui

This problem which I know should be very easy has stumped me for hours.

I try to get a random element from a simple `Array` into a `Text` in `SwiftUI` but i get errors I don't understand, the recent error I got was:

> Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that '[Result]' conform
>   to '_FormatSpecifiable'

What would be the simplest way to implement this? 
I understand this has been answered many times but I am too bad at coding to understand when I try to google it.

```
struct Result: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showDetails = false

    @State var results = [Result(score: 8),
                          Result(score: 5),
                          Result(score: 10)]


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {   
                self.results.randomElement()
            }) {
                Text("Button title, \(results)")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you want to pick a random result from the array every time you click the button _or_ shuffle the array and display the list in random order?

Comment: yes the first one, random element everytime i press the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `results` aren't changing, there's no need for `@State` (coupled with an initializer on `Result` so we can easily map a list of scores).
Instead, we want to introduce a new variable to hold a random `Result` and mark *that* as a state. So each time we press the button, we set a new random result and trigger a view update.

Please note that I have marked the var as optional (since I do not know the logic behind any initial value) and displaying a `0` if this thing is `nil` (probably not what you want in your final code - you can decide whatever default value, or conditional view display, makes sense for you)

```
struct Result: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var score: Int
    init(_ score: Int) {
        self.score = score
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showDetails = false

    let results = [8, 5, 10].map(Result.init)

    @State var randomResult: Result?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {   
                self.randomResult = self.results.randomElement()
            }) {
                Text("Button title, \(randomResult?.score ?? 0)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Would i do it this way with strings aswell?

Comment: Sure! The type of the objects in the array is irrelevant.

Comment: it says that it cannot convert the int to a string?